# VS2010 MSBuild Target only runs on rebuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm currently attempting to build a C++ library and what I would like is that every time the build button is pressed I would get all of the include files to be moved to a certain directory.

What I currently have is this

```
<Target Name="CopyToIncludeFiles">
  <Message Text="Copying All '*.h' and '*.hpp' to the include directory" Importance="high">
  </Message>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ClInclude)" DestinationFolder="..\HelperLib\x86\include\">
  </Copy>
</Target>
```

And I include the target in the DefaultTargets likes so

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build;CopyToIncludeFiles;" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

This all works fine so long as I use the rebuild, yet this never runs when I just hit build.

What do I need to do to have this run whether I hit build or rebuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think task you solving easier to do with `PreBuild Event` in project properties, as it is just simple command-line command.

If you still want msbuild - you may use `BeforeTargets` like this:

```
<Target Name="CopyToIncludeFiles" BeforeTargets="Rebuild;Build">
  <Message Text="Copying All '*.h' and '*.hpp' to the include directory" Importance="high" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ClInclude)" DestinationFolder="..\HelperLib\x86\include\"  />
</Target>
```

You should not change project `DefaultTargets` property to include your task.

Also notice that both PreBuild event and this msbuild task **will not run** in case your project code doesn't require recompilation (i.e. no cpp / h files changed).